# Setting target variable for the name of the makefile from a subdirectory

Tags: makefile

How can I have the variable for $(MAKEFILE) be defined during target execution?
Basically I have a few make files in subdirectories that are named for a specific platform "Makefile.aix" and just Makefile in all other directories. I would like to set a variable for $(MAKEFILE) that gets defined in each subdirectory. Code would look something like this.

```
MAKEFILE = Makefile

SUBDIR = ./sub ./sub2

    ifneq ($(wildcard Makefile),)
            MAKEFILE = Makefile
    else
            MAKEFILE = Makefile.$(PLATFORM)
    endif


    all:;
            @for i in $(SUBDIR);\
                    do (\
                            echo Making $$i ...;\
                            cd $$i;\
                            make -f $(MAKEFILE)\
                    ); done
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there just one `Makefile.$(PLATFORM)` in each subdirectory, or are there several, for different platforms?
In the first case, you could do something like this:

```
SUBDIR = ./sub ./sub2

define script
cd $(1); \
$(MAKE) -f Makefile*

endef

all:
    $(foreach dir, $(SUBDIR), $(call script,$(dir)))
```

(The empty line inside the define is significant. It can be omitted, if you add a semicolon at the end of the line `$(MAKE) ...`, leading to one long command line, containing the commands for all directories, which will then be executed in one chunk.)

An alternative `script` would be (just a matter of personal preference which you like better):

```
define script
$(MAKE) -C $(1) -f $(notdir $(wildcard $(1)/Makefile*))

endef
```

If there are several `Makefile.$(PLATFORM)` files in a directory it becomes more difficult. I'll have to think about that one some more.

UPDATE: In response to your comment, something like this should work:

```
define script
$(MAKE) -C $(1) -f $(notdir $(wildcard $(1)/Makefile $(1)/Makefile.$(PLATFORM)))

endef
```

Comment: There are several different platforms in a few sub directories. "Makefile.aix, Makefile.sun, Makefile.hpux"

Comment: @Marc: OK, I've updated my answer. I assume `$(PLATFORM)` is defined beforehand to one of those options, right?

Comment: @eriktous. I'm getting an error after making the changes to my test makefile                                                           "Unix:/src> make all
make -C  ./sub -f Makefile  make -C  ./sub2 -f Makefile.aix
make: *** ./sub2: A file or directory in the path name does not exist..  Stop.
make: *** [all] Error 2"

Comment: @Marc: I can't tell with this formatting, but do those two make commands appear on one line? If so, do you have the empty line (or semicolon) inside the `define ... endef`? The foreach function evaluates `$(call script,$(dir))` for each directory and then concatenates the outputs. Without the empty line (or more importantly, the newline character on the preceding line) it all becomes one long command, invoking `make` with a lot of arguments that don't make sense to it. With the newline or semicolon the commands get interpreted separately, as intended.

Comment: @eriktous: Thanks! It worked. I didn't have the newline. One more thing. I was hopping not to have to recreate all my targets or at least not to change the target code to drastically. Is there a way to use a variable $(MAKEFILE) to call that define script? Basically I would like to keep the targets as close to my example above as possible.

Comment: @Marc: I don't fully understand your question. I guess you mean recipes when you say targets. If so, the recipe in your example above is trying to mix makefile scope with shell scope, which is not possible. First $(MAKEFILE) is expanded and then the resulting command is sent to the shell. If you want the shell to perform the loop over the directories, you have to use shell commands to find the appropriate makefile for each directory (as in the example pmod gave in his answer).

Answer (score 0):

Following your logic, I'd propose update do () section with:

```
                do (\
                        echo Making $$i ...;\
                        cd $$i;\
                        if [ -f Makefile.$(PLATFORM) ] \
                        then\
                          make -f Makefile.$(PLATFORM) \
                        else\
                          make -f Makefile\
                        fi\
                ); done
```

This is actually not a make style, but I can't suggest anything better without specific of your project

Answer (score 0):

You can do most of this, including the loop over directories, using GNU make's built-in functions. Put the following in a central place, say `$(TOP_DIR)/mk/subdir.mk`:

```
makefile-for-dir = \
  $(if $(wildcard $(1)/Makefile),Makefile,Makefile.$(PLATFORM))

make-recursive = \
  $(foreach _d,$(1),$(MAKE) -C $(_d) -f $(call makefile-for-dir,$(_d)) && ) :
```

In each makefile that start recursive makes, use

```
include $(TOP_DIR)/mk/subdir.mk

SUBDIRS = dir1 dir2 dir3

.PHONY: all
all:
    +@$(call make-recursive,$(SUBDIRS))
```